# How to select option from Right Click using Sikuli API

Tags: java, sikuli

I am using Sikuli Java API to verify screens in a Eclipse Based Application.
Now I am struck with Performing Right Click on a Task and Do a Right Mouse Click and select a Option

I have heard about Key Modifiers but how to use it I am not sure.

Kindly suggest your ways

Comment: If you'd waited for a while, you'd see the answer here: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/234425

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completly understand about this question, but when I want to select option after right click

1. I will check the options it have short key or not (like Delete, it
   can use type(Key.DELETE) instead)
2. or it have not, I just capture menu image and click it

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link on how to use Mouse/Keyboard actions - http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#low-level-mouse-and-keyboard-actions.

1. Do a mouse right click
2. Do a sikuli click based on screenshot of the option